# Calling GAE NDB query with dynamic property name

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google AppEngine NDB queries are strange beasts.
Say I have a class (and ndb entity) of Car
with color and weight properties.
I can do

```
Car.query(Car.color == "blue")
```

I've never seen any Python 2 documentation on this kind of "function call".
How many arguments are being passed? Logically it would be one
that is a Boolean, but apparently "query" can find out the source
code of that argument and get Car.color, ==, and  "blue".
Is it possible for developers to define these kind of functions,
or is this some compiler hack?

My real problem is that I have a user input dialog that has
fields for the class ("Car" in this case) 
the property ("color" in this case)
and the value, ("blue" in this case).
How can I construct and call a query that takes those inputs?

Answer (score 4):

This is done by python [magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html), your sample uses `__eq__`.

To construct a query you can use something like this:

```
Car.query(getattr(Car, 'color') == 'red')
```

Be sure to check if property exists by calling `hasattr(Car, 'color')`

Comment: magic methods document has lots of doc for the counter-intuitive design of python, esp w.r.t. infix operators. But it does not address the issue of the CALLING mechanism of query whereby we have the body of the query method apparently getting information from the call source code that *shouldn't* be available.

Comment: This `Car.color == "blue"` returns specific value, in that case -- its filter object with specific params -- its easy.

Comment: There is no issue with the calling mechanism.  You are calling query with an argument.  It just so happens the expression 'Car.color == "blue"' resolves to a filter object that is passed to the query as per any standard python calling convention.  You need to look at the distinction between expressions and single arguments.  `expression = Car.colr == 'blue'`  and then query(expression)

Comment: == is documented in Python 2 documentation to return True or False. Google has cleverly over-ridden this expected behavior with a special == definition for field objects to return a filter object.

Comment: I had a bug in this code because TextProperty fields are not indexed by default (like most other entity properties). Combined with the lousy error message, and TextProperty's unusual behavior, such a clever hack on Google's part is more damaging than beneficial. Dimitry's, Tim's and frustrating hours of my time allowed me to work around these language design flaws. Hopefully this thread will help others overcome Google's mistake.

Comment: `__eq__` method may returns anything, not only True or False. NDB written by Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, do you think that he is really did a mistake here? And, please, accept an answer **if** your problem is solved.